# Preciso unir duas colunas de DATE e TIME com a classe POSIXct mas me retorna NA

Tags: r

Preciso criar um DateTime unindo essas duas colunas com a classe POSIXct. Mas ao retornar a tabela o DateTime vem com NA.

Edt. Ao seguir a sugestão do amigo abaixo só apareceu as três colunas iniciais. Minha tabela tem mais colunas. Havia colocado aqui apenas três para exemplificar para não ficar grande demais aqui.(Minha planilha base tem mais tês colunas).

Seguem amostra de dados para reprodução:

```
 Mycbon
Date        Time      Receiver  Transmitter ID  Transmitter.Serial  Sensor Value    
2019-04-29  05:31:33    134321  4844    Ane  1305232           28.7  °C     PRN
2019-04-29  08:52:08    134325  4861    Bob  1305233           4.2    m     MVW



    class(mycbon$Date)
    class(mycbon$Time)
    mycbon$DateTime <- strptime(paste(mycbon$Date, mycbon$Time), %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:OS")
    mycbon$DateTime<-as.character(mycbon$DateTime)
    mycbon$DateTime<-as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(mycbon$DateTime),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))
    str(mycbon)
    mycbon[,3:12]->myc
    myc <- myc[c("DateTime","Receiver", "Transmitter","ID", "Transmitter.Serial", "Sensor", "Value")]
    head(myc)
```

Comment: Por favor, faça um exemplo reproduzível e uma pergunta mais bem estruturada.

Comment: Qual a classe das colunas Date e Time? Forneça um exemplo melhor dos seus dados, por exemplo postando a saída de `dput(head(mycbon))`.

Answer (score 0):

Os NAs são gerados por causa dos espaços extras ao passar o formato para `strptime`.

```
mycbon <- read.table(text = "
  Date         Time      Receiver Transmitter
  29/04/2019  05:31:33    134156  4822
  29/04/2019  08:52:08    134158  4823",
  header = TRUE)

DateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(mycbon$Date, mycbon$Time),
                       format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

> cbind(DateTime, mycbon[, 3:ncol(mycbon)])
             DateTime Receiver Transmitter
1 2019-04-29 05:31:33   134156        4822
2 2019-04-29 08:52:08   134158        4823
```

OBS: as.POSIXct já faz internamente a chamada para strptime, não é necessário usar `as.POSIXct(strptime(...))`

Comment: Eu retirei os espaços do formato e eliminei a linha do `as.POSIXct mas continua resultando em NA                                                                                                             
 ```                                                                                                     class(mycbon$Date)
class(mycbon$Time)
mycbon$DateTime <- strptime(paste(mycbon$Date, mycbon$Time), "%Y/%m/%d% H:%M:%OS")
mycbon$DateTime<-as.character(mycbon$DateTime)
str(mycbon)
mycbon[,3:12]->myc
myc <- myc[c("DateTime","Receiver", "Transmitter")]
head(myc)

Comment: Como faço para aparecer aqui na resposta os comandos em cinza separados do texto? Respondi mas ficou tudo junto. Obg

Comment: Não faz, a sessão de comentários não é para isso.

Comment: Veja o formato que está passando para `strptime`: ele deve bater com o dos seus dados, não com o formato que quer no final.

Comment: já corrigi, mas continua os NAs. Atualizei as informações acima. Espero que consigam me ajudar a resolver esse problema. Obg.

Comment: Preste atenção no seu código, é só um erro de digitação.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigada!